# MyTop shortens the database name length

Tags: mysql, database, ssh

sorry for my poor grammar.

I have question about MyTop ssh db monitor. Some of my database is longer then obviously MyTop can display.

For example **"nameofdomain_database"**. The next is named **"nameofdomain_data_all"**.

MyTop displays **"nameofdomain_da"** and i can't be sure which one is in use in real time.

**Keep in mind - shorting the database name is not an option.**

Is there are someone with the same issue.

I wondering is there an option to increase the numbers of characters in DB column in order to see the full name?

Or something like that!

Thanks